# Terminal MacOS emoji support

Tags: macos, terminal, emoji, utf-8

I was just wondering if anyone knows the emoji support that the Terminal.app has in MacOS? I'm using zsh, and I end up with this when I type it out, I get the following (note I didn't add a space after the flag on the first one, but added a space on the second one but in both cases you can see there's an overlap on the flag, also note the duplication on the spaces and f on the end of the input)

[image: terminal input with overlapping emoji and text]

And when using vim I also get

[image: vim input showing overlapping emoji and text]

How do people resolve this?

Comment: I usually add spaces after emojis to avoid that problem.

Comment: The emoji are double-width characters.